# Multiple LINQ query error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having an issue calling similar LINQ queries on the same data set in Visual Studio.  Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix this?

This is what I'm trying to do, which bombs:

```
Dim raw = db.GetRawData()
GridView2.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "A")
GridView3.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "B")
GridView2.DataBind()
GridView3.DataBind()
```

But this works:

```
GridView2.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "A")
GridView3.DataSource = otherdata
```

And so does this:

```
GridView2.DataSource = otherdata
GridView3.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "B")
```

And this doesn't even work:

```
GridView2.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "A")
GridView3.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "A")
```

So the fact that I'm calling a similar query multiple times seems to be an issue.

Comment: Could you please post the actual error?

Comment: It occurs on execution of the web page.  The error is 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing immediate execution using ToList() does the trick:

```
Dim raw = db.GetRawData().ToList()
GridView2.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "A")
GridView3.DataSource = (From p In raw Select p.Nme, p.val).Where(Function(w) w.Grade = "B")
GridView2.DataBind()
GridView3.DataBind()
```